# Debugging app compiled with Visual Studio 6.0 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to debug a project developed in visual studio 2010 and it loads VC++6 (VisualStudio 6) DLLs. Unfortunately I am unable to see the VC++6 DLL process under "Attach to process".

When I searched on the net I found the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cta4x5hc(v=vs.80).aspx  article and it suggested to add /ASSEMBLYDEBUG when building vc++6 DLL. But then I get "Command line warning D4002 : ignoring unknown option '/ASSEMBLYDEBUG'  ".

So can some one tell me whether it is possible to debug a VC++6 DLL from visual studio 2010.

regards

Upu

Comment: Hi Roger, I am totally new to windows development environment hence I may lack some obvious things!. But anyway I will try to expand the problem I am facing. I have a VC++ 6(VisulStudio6) DLL, corresponding interop file for VC++6 DLL, and C# application developed using VS2010. VC++6 DLLs are build disabling optimisation and with /ZI flag set. so they have the corresponding .pdb file. however interop DLL does not have .pdb file as expected. c# application uses the interop DLLs!. Now I am running the C# application in VS2010 and trying to put break point in my VC++6 code.

Comment: the breakpoints are not hitting and this is my main problem. whilst I am runing c# application I check the C# application process  related DLLs from processexplorer and then I can see both VC++6 DLL and interop DLL. But when I check the modules from VS2010 I can only see the interop DLL and not the VC++ DLL. against introp DLL it says symbols are not loaded. SO please let me know whether I could step into VC++ DLL. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to attach. DLL is loaded into host process. So just start debugging you project that loads the dll. if you have pdb and source code of the dll, you will be able to set breakpoint in dll code.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL's wont show up as a "process" in the debugger, they're part of the process that loads and uses the DLL's (i.e. the main application).

So yes, you can debug them with VS2010, you can just launch the app written in VS2010 (or attach to it in the debugger) and you should see the DLL's loaded in that.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the prompt response., but the problem is when when I try to attach the process I cannot see VC++6 DLL. However if I run th eprocessExplorer then I can see VC++6 DLL process. So studio 2010 did not see it. Furthermore, as I am using an interop DLL for my original VC++6 DLL I do not see my original DLL in the module list. thanks Upu

Comment: @user566995 Are you seeing the DLL in the optional lower pane in ProcessExplorer? If so, that's just the DLL's loaded by the process highlighted above, not a process in it's own right. The DLL's shouldn't be showing up in the process part on their own.

Comment: Hi, I do the things in following order, first start the vs2010 porject in debug mode, then when I select that proces from ProcessExplorer I can see all the DLL associated with it. In there I can see my VC++6 DLLs. But As I said from VS2010 I cannot see them. Can this be due to interop DLL (This is corresponding to my VC++6 DLL). Thanks